# Drush needs a higher bootstrap level to run

Tags: drush

Do you have any idea on what might be causing this error when I execute:

```
drush si geoslate --db-url='mysql://root:root@localhost/geoslate' --site-name=Geoslate
```

> Command site-install needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke  from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   The drush command 'si vimn_geoslate' could not be executed.
>   A Drupal installation directory could not be found

?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This particular error happens when drush cannot find the settings.php file to read in and "bootstrap" itself.

You need to cd into the drupal directory (Document root) of your drupal install in order for it to read in a settings.php file.

Comment: Further to this, you may need to use the -r option to specify the root in some setups.

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but can you elaborate on why a settings.php file is needed for a `drush site-install` command, which normally creates this file?

Comment: Somewhat related to @mpdonadio's comment above, it was not immediately obvious to me that this drush site-install command doesn't actually download Drupal. You need to run something like `drush dl drupal-7.x` first, then run the Drush command from inside this newly-downloaded Drupal folder.

Answer (score 2):

For that error: Drush needs a higher bootstrap level to run

Write on your terminal: `mysql`

if you see something that:

> Unknown command 'mysql'

Then the problem comes from mysql, that's why your drush commands don't work.

Install MySql by Brew: https://brew.sh

```
Brew install mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to install and enable some modules I encountered with this error. by changing the line `'host' => 'localhost'` in settings.php file of my site to `'host' => php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '127.0.0.1' : 'localhost'` now I can install my modules through Drush.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue and I tried the accepted answer, which didn't work for me. As this question turns up high on Google results, I'm offering my solution in the hope that it helps others in my situation.

In my case, the mysql-client package was not installed. `apt-get install mysql-client` fixed Drush for me.

Why didn't I have the mysql-client package installed on a Drupal development machine? I'm developing on Windows and using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) for Drush purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Setup an alias for your site in the alias.drushrc.php file.  Make sure MySQL executable is in your path variable.