# Cannot update modules with drush – needs higher bootstrap level

Tags: 7, drush

As stated in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69552/drush-needs-a-higher-bootstrap-level-to-run) Drush needs to find the settings.php file in order to work. My problem is that the settings.php file is indeed in the right folder (and I have navigated to the Drupal root folder before issuing the Drush commands), but it still does not work to update modules with drush. I just get the message that `Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run`. It even states itself that the Drupal settings file is located in `sites/default/settings.php.`

This is the error message:

```
C:\wamp\www>drush ups
Command pm-updatestatus needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you      [error] will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment
to run this command.
The drush command 'ups' could not be executed.                           [error]

Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.             [error]
```

I have also followed the instructions in [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1428638), with no luck.

What else can I try?

Comment: Yes I am. In my case it's C:/wamp/www

Comment: try with sudo, ex: `sudo [your drush command]`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am on Windows 7. No sudo command available. But I will try to run as admin...

Comment: And no, that didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer that I could adapt to my WAMP environment [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/881676#comment-11799063). I simply added `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin` to the PATH, and then Drush worked also for updates.